# Evento validación calendar en Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, xhtml

Tengo 2 elementos de **PrimeFaces**, en donde uno es `inputText` y el otro es `calendar`, en donde tengo una validación que capturo a través de un evento. 
En el `input` no tengo problemas, pero en el `calendar` no me funciona, debido a que es gatillado por el evento `keyUp` y en el `calendar` no se puede escribir, por ende nunca ingresa.

Mi pregunta es, ¿Qué evento debería poner para que me funcione?

**INPUT (SIN PROBLEMAS):**

```
 <p:inputText  id="input2" class="ui-g-3" style="font-size:9px;margin-top:10px" value="#{varComponente.valor2}">
    <p:keyFilter regEx="/[0123456789]/i"/>
    <p:ajax listener="#{crearEstrategiaBeans.ValidaCambioInput}" event="keyup" update=":formCrear:parentPanel3 :formCrear:btnGenerarLista"/>
 </p:inputText>
```

**CALENDAR (CON PROBLEMAS):**

```
<p:calendar style="margin-left:5px;margin:top:10px;" inputStyle="width:25%"  value="#{varComponente.fecha1}">
    <p:keyFilter regEx="/[]/i"/>
    <p:ajax listener="#{crearEstrategiaBeans.ValidaCambioInput}" event="keyup" update=":formCrear:parentPanel3 :formCrear:btnGenerarLista"/>
</p:calendar>
```

Comment: La respuesta la encontré acá: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099478/value-change-listner-not-working-in-primefaces-calendar